# R reshape2 'Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length'

Tags: r, reshape2

I have seen this reshape2 several times on SO but haven't seen a solution to my particular problem;

I have a dataset like this;

```
head(data)
student    test    score
Adam      Exam1     80
Adam      Exam2     90
John      Exam1     70
John      Exam2     60
```

I am trying to cast this to a wide format that looks like this;

```
Student    Exam1    Exam2 ........ ExamX
Adam         80       90
John         70       60
```

using;

```
dcast(data,student~test,value.var='score')
```

but the data ends up looking like something like this;

```
Student    Exam1     Exam2
Adam        0          0
John        0          1
```

with this error;

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

Any ideas why it is changing all of these values to a (0 or 1)?

Comment: You need to provide a sequence column.  But, based on the example, it works though `dcast(data, student~test, value.var='score')`  Provide an example with duplicate rows

Comment: It's not an error. It's a warning to let you know that since you didn't provide a value for `fun.aggregate` (e.g., `fun.aggregate=mean`), it defaults to returning the length, which is a count of the number of rows falling into that combination of categories. I don't see `job_type` in your sample data. Did you want `dcast(data,student ~ test ,value.var='score')`?

Comment: Hi, i have similar problem now, and i dont know how to fix this. Was the problem, that `value.var` was wrong typed?

Comment: @Bobesh: It's some time ago but still: Sometimes a simple `object <- unique(object)` works as the problem can be caused by identical duplicate rows.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge What is object in this case?

Comment: @VijayRamesh Works on data frames/data tables, vectors and arrays.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to @akrun who pointed it out.

Well, there's a high chance that your data has duplicate row that look either like this:

```
student    test    score
Adam      Exam1     80
Adam      Exam1     85
Adam      Exam2     90
John      Exam1     70
John      Exam2     60
```

Or like this:

```
student   class     test    score
Adam      Biology   Exam1     80
Adam      Theology  Exam1     85
Adam      Theology  Exam2     90
John      Biology   Exam1     70
John      Theology  Exam2     60
```

When you cast it like this: `dcast(data, student + class ~ test, value.var='score')`

Comment: Still getting the same error as above. I followed your suggestion. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried the dcast(data, student ~ test, value.var='score'), but it gives the same error and a 0-1 matrix.

Comment: it migth be worth checking that there are no duplicated rows, perhaps due to NAs